# eclipse can't change elements attribute on dots "..."

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

when i add `EditText` field to activity, i can't change inputType attribute at `Propertise` window.
There are dots(`...`) on that field, but when i click, nothing happens, same is with background, i don't even get dialog to choose option.

It works when i add this text in xml file:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/egg_shell" >
</TableRow>
```

But i am begginer at android development, i need that option, like on tutorials.

How to fix that?

Comment: post your complete xml file to investigate in this problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with the Graphical Layout when you are rendering layouts in Eclipse for Android-19 (KitKat). You cannot change items in the Properties window for example.

Switching to Android-18 in Graphical Layout (green Android top-right) is a workaround.

Comment: i changed android version in project from 4.4 to 4.3 now i don't have anything to propertise, no options there :/

Comment: You don't need to change the properties of the project, you can leave it at 4.4. Look at the window in which you design your screen/layout. On the top-right you see a green Android-figure, change this to 18.